# JavaScript displaying word "null" in CRM 2011 fields w/ no value

Tags: javascript, null, integer, crm, getelementbyid

I am using the following code to remove commas from an integer (whole number) field in CRM 2011:

`function Form_onload()
{
document.getElementById("new_universalid").value =Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_universalid").getValue();
}`

The issue is that for any accounts/contacts w/out a value for 'new_universalid', it's displaying the word "null".

My goal is to display a blank field, rather than the word NULL.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can explain it and that is most obvious to understand is as follows, simply check to make sure the value is not null before assigning:

```
function Form_onload()
{
    var new_uid=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_universalid").getValue();
    if(new_uid != null){
        document.getElementById("new_universalid").value = new_uid;
    }
}
```